# Python: Getting desired value from Twilio's POST Request

Tags: python, django, parsing, request, twilio

After setting everything correctly I've observed that my app receives an SMS from Twilio API as a request. When I apply:

```
for i in request:
  print i
```

*i* only shows one value which is something like:

```
AccountSid=<some_value>&Body=<msg>&ToZip=<zipCode>&FromState=&ToCity=<cityName>
```

My question is how to get the **body** value from quest. I tried *request['Body']* but it failed.

Answer (score 3):

I use Django and it may or may not be the same:

```
body = request.REQUEST.get('Body', None)
from_number = request.REQUEST.get('From', None)
```

These are the main [parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) I look for.

Comment: Thanks for editing this! This is a bit old, do you know how to see what it said before?